# Deprecation warning: `np.float` is a deprecated alias for the builtin `float`

Tags: python, numpy, k-means, deprecation-warning

[image]

Does anyone know why when I convert to float, X is still called as numpy.float as it is giving me deprecation issues when I try to run X through the elbow method for K-Means Clustering

Comment: `np.float` was removed in the latest `numpy` version (1.24?), with warnings earlier.  But not all packages have been updated to change that.  We've been seeing issues like this since 1.24 was put out.  Typically the solution is to update the problem package, or move back on the numpy version until these differences have been corrected.